# Actionscript 3.0....x>y>z not working

Tags: actionscript-3, operators

probably a pretty simple question here, but I find it weird. Luckily I found a way around it, but the fact that what I did works and what I have in the title doesn't work is confusing the hell out of me!

I just have a simple if statement...then execute a function. This code works:

```
if (200 > (x-target.x) && (x-target.x) > 0)
                fireWeapon();
```

yet this code doesn't!

```
if (200 > (x-target.x) > 0)
                fireWeapon();
```

AS3 does not give me an error either....It just simply does an if statement for the condition

```
if (200 > (x-target.x))
```

and seems to ignore the statement where it must be greater than 0. I would like to use the shorter, more mathematically nice looking method in the future, so let me know if there is a way around doing the && sign! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (200 > (x-target.x) > 0)` code is working. but what you think is different. computer in order to interpret one sentence. Is evaluated as follows.

> 1) 200 > ( x-target.x ) If 200 is larger than (x-target.x) return true, not false.
>
> 2) true(1) or false(0) > 0 If left-statement is true return true,(because 1 is larger than 0) not false.

As a result, If 200 is larger than (x-target.x) always return true, not false. In general, the syntax used in the computer language is not the same as mathematic syntax.

And you want `x> y> z` must change to `x>y && y>z && x>z`.